# Using Other Datatypes then char to create a TSVECTOR in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, types, triggers, full-text-search, tsvector

I have set up a trigger like:

```
     create trigger customer_search_update before update or
               insert on table
               for each row execute procedure
               tsvector_update_trigger( search_tsvector,'pg_catalog.english',
                                      id,
                                      name
```

but when I now try to enter the ID I get the error:

```
     Error column "id" is not of a character type
```

So how I transform these int datatyp or at general other datatypes to char / string.